# Proving a language is Not Regular without using Pumping Lemma?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, pumping-lemma

I was wondering how one would go about proving a language is Not Regular without using the traditional pumping lemma contradiction.

$$L = \{ 1^k 0^n 1^n 0^k \mid k \geq 0, n \geq 0\}$$

I've seen a method before where you would Intersect this language with another one and show that the result is Not regular. But I'm lost on what to intersect it with.

Comment: Isn't that a circular problem? If you intersect with a regular language, how would you prove that the resulting language is not regular?

Comment: @siracusa You already know some languages are not regular.

Comment: Intersect with $0^*1^*$.